# Как отправить видео в "Кружке" (app.send_video_note()) pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, pyrogram

Есть проблема в отправке видео в кружке по типу

```
@app.on_message(filters.command("Круг З", prefixes="*"))
def circlzb(_,msg):
    app.send_video_note(msg.chat.id, 'Vidz.mp4')

@app.on_message(filters.command("Круг М", prefixes="*"))
def circlrom(_,msg):
    app.send_video_note(msg.chat.id, 'Vidm.mp4')
```

В первом случае видео(з) отправляется кружком, а видео(м) отправлается кваратом. Оба видео обрезаны до соотношения сторон 1:1. Мне нужны видео кружки. Есть боты в тг которые делают эти кружки но они по большой степени платные, я хочу понять как эти боты работают изнутри.

Answer (score 0):

Платные боты работают по принципу подгонки видео по всем параметрам: 8мб макс вес, соотношение сторон 1:1, видео не дольше минуты, а потом делают с него кружок